# About aligned storage and trivially copyable/destructible types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, undefined-behavior

I had an interesting discussion with a guy smarter than me and I remained with an open question about aligned storage and trivially copyable/destructible types.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

struct type {
    using storage_type = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(void *), alignof(void *)>;
    using fn_type = int(storage_type &);

    template<typename T>
    static int proto(storage_type &storage) {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>);
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>);
        return *reinterpret_cast<T *>(&storage);
    }

    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(void *), alignof(void *)> storage;
    fn_type *fn;
    bool weak;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<type>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<type>);

    std::vector<type> vec;

    type t1;
    new (&t1.storage) char{'c'};
    t1.fn = &type::proto<char>;
    t1.weak = true;
    vec.push_back(t1);

    type t2;
    new (&t2.storage) int{42};
    t2.fn = &type::proto<int>;
    t2.weak = false;
    vec.push_back(t2);

    vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto &t) { return t.weak; }), vec.end());

    assert(vec.size() == 1);
    assert(!vec[0].weak);
    assert(vec[0].fn(vec[0].storage) == 42);
}
```

This is a simplified version of a real world case. I really hope I didn't make errors or simplified it too much.

As you can see, the idea is that there exists a type called `type` (naming things is hard, you know) having three data members:

- `storage` that is a bunch of byte having size `sizeof(void *)`
- `fn` a pointer to a function having type `int(storage_type &)`
- `weak` an useless bool used only to introduce the example

To create new instances of `type` (see the `main` function), I put a value (either an `int` or a `char`) in the storage area and the right specialization of the static function template `proto` in `fn`.
Later on, when I want to *invoke* `fn` and get the integer value it returns, I do something like this:

```
int value = type_instance.fn(type_instance.storage);
```

So far, so good. Despite the fact of being risky and error-prone (but this is an example, the real use case is not), this *works*.
Note that `type` and all the types I put in the storage (`int` and `char` in the example) are required to be both trivially copyable and trivially destructible. This is also the core of the discussion I had.

The *problem* (or better, the *doubt*) arises when I put instances of types eg in a vector (see the `main` function) and decide to remove one of them from within the array, so that some of the others are moved around to keep it packed.
More in general, I'm no longer that sure about what happens when I want to copy or move instances of `type` and if it's UB or not.

My guess was that it was allowed being the types put in the storage trivially copyable and trivially destructible. On the other side, I've been told that this isn't directly allowed by the standard and it can be considered a *benign UB*, because almost all the compilers in fact allows you to do that (I can guarantee this, it seemes to *work* everywhere for some definitions of *work*).

So, the question is: is this allowed or UB and what can I do to work around the issue in the second case? Moreover, is C++20 going to change things for that?

Comment: Doesn't `new (&t1.storage) double{1.}` UB if `alignof(void*) < alignof(double)` and `sizeof(void*) < sizeof(double)` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk ok, my fault, ignore the double, I'm changing it to char. The real code has a test on sizes.

Comment: `*reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage);` IRC, this is UB, since you cannot directly access an object of some type `T` through a pointer of type `U*`, even if you are 100% sure that an object of type `T` is there. C++17 addresses this issue with [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about what happens to objects created in some storage when you copy/move the storage. Formally speaking, no objects do appear in a copy of the storage. See related issue: [CWG2325](http://wg21.link/cwg2325)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer so, it's technically UB, even though no compiler exploits it and almost everywhere _it works_ (granted, it could break tomorrow). Are you saying this?

Comment: _Are you saying this?_ If I understand your question correctly, then yes.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yeah, well, the question can be seen as - _am I allowed to use the storage area of an instance of type obtained by a copy/move as it happens in `assert(vec[0].fn(vec[0].storage) == 42);` after the erase-remove?_

Comment: I think your code demonstrates the issue in a rather complicated way. Is it equivalent to https://pastebin.com/wT1fM5As ? You need something like [p0593](http://wg21.link/p0593r2) to be accepted to have the behavior defined.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I agree that the example is rather complicated. I'm also half-way in a process of understanding what I wanted to ask. It's curious that this doesn't work out-of-the-box btw. As the document you linked pointed out, this makes really complicated to _translate_ bytes received from the network to objects, in a sense.

Comment: In all reality, the result of the question shouldn't hamper your ability to write net code. The standard isn't exactly perfect, trust your compiler.

Comment: @PasserBy yeah, that's why the guy with which I was discussing called it a _benign UB_. To sum up the thought - _it's technically UB, but it works for all compilers, so who cares? at least until it breaks._

Comment: @LanguageLawyer what if I memcpy the object into the storage, then memcpy the storage in a new instance within `proto`? This way, the copy of the storage should be allowed and the UB should go away being the types trivially copyable. I'm no longer assuming that the storage contains a valid instance because I use it only as raw bytes to copy around. Am I wrong? If it's unclear what I mean, I can pack an example in a hour (I'm out of office at the moment).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I meant something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iTnK12kgYATZPq1Z). In this case, I don't expect to find a valid object in the storage area. Instead, I memcpy back and forth trivially copyable types. When `type` is copied, the storage area is copied as-is, but it should be fine as well. Am I missing something? At a first glance, it's not anymore in the UB land of the original example.

Comment: @skypjack is it necessary for the example be so long?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer probably not, but it's close to real case this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem reduces to basically what [LanguageLawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512451/about-aligned-storage-and-trivially-copyable-destructible-types#comment95832607_54512451) suggested:

> ```
> alignas(int) unsigned char buff1[sizeof(int)];
> alignas(int) unsigned char buff2[sizeof(int)];
>
> new (buff1) int {42};
> std::memcpy(buff2, buff1, sizeof(buff1));
>
> assert(*std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int*>(buff2)) == 42); // is it ok?
> ```

In other words - when I copy bytes around, do I also copy around "object-ness"? `buff1` is certainly providing storage for an `int` - when we copy those bytes, does `buff2` also now provide storage for an `int`?

And the answer is... no. There are exactly [four ways](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1.sentence-2) to create an object, per [intro.object]:

> An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression ([expr.new]), when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created ([conv.rval], [class.temporary]).

None of those things happened here, so we don't have an object in `buff2` of any kind (outside of just the normal array of `unsigned char`), hence behavior is undefined. Simply put, `memcpy` does not create objects.

In the original example, it's only the 3rd line that requires that implicit object creation:

```
assert(vec.size() == 1); // ok
assert(!vec[0].weak);    // ok
assert(vec[0].fn(vec[0].storage) == 42); // UB
```

---

This is why [P0593](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r3.html) exists and has a special section for `memmove`/`memcpy`:

> A call to memmove behaves as if it
>
> - copies the source storage to a temporary area
> - implicitly creates objects in the destination storage, and then
> - copies the temporary storage to the destination storage.
>
> This permits memmove to preserve the types of trivially-copyable objects, or to be used to reinterpret a byte representation of one object as that of another object.

This is what you need here - that implicit object creation step is currently missing from C++ today.

---

That said, you can more or less rely on this "doing the right thing" given the simply enormous body of C++ code that exists today relies on this code to "just work."

Comment: As a side question, the example in my last comment is instead legal code? I use memcpy to work around it, according to what you said it should be no longer UB. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack: And what happens if `T` is not default constructible?

Comment: Now I'm not so sure I understood correctly. The example given later in comments looks more like that the question is whether it is ok to copy from an object to an array, move the array and copy back to different object of the same type. Something like a mix of https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#2 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#3

Comment: @NicolBolas good point, but I'm using it for primitive types and I can set an assert on it being default constructible in the original code. In this case, would it be correct or still UB?

Comment: @Language There and back again - to the original storage which has an object in it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer no, the example in the comment is a slightly modified one that should work. Is it still UB? It seems to me that it is allowed by the language.

Comment: @skypjack could you make a minimal example? Are this function pointers, vector erases etc. so important?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer in the real code, the _problem_ arises from the fact that I put something a bit more elaborated than `type` into vectors and erase/remove things, so instances are moved around and buffers are copied. I'm pretty sure we can pack a different example, but I'm interested in what happens when it comes to working with vectors.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer btw, [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IZzk9lzoYgDHP887) is more or less a simplified version of the second example. That is: I memcpy an `int` in a storage area, copy the storage area somewhere else, then memcpy the copy of the storage area in another `int`. As long as types involved (`int` in this case) are trivially copyable, trivially destructible and default constructible, this should work and be allowed by the language. Does it make sense?

Comment: @skypjack I would say this is underspecified. Copying from a trivially copyable object to a character array and back is defined, and copying from a trivially copyable object to another object of the same type is also explicitly defined. What happens if one combine this actions? I'm not sure. It is always safe to declare something which is not clearly defined as undefined or at least underspecified if you believe it is intended to be defined but this is not clear enough.

Comment: @Barry ? is it really unspecified? It seems to me it's defined. Otherwise what would be the purpose of allowing to copy a trivially copyable object in a buffer and copy it back if not to send it over a network or whatever and thus copy it in a different instance? I don't see the point to copy it in the instance that generated the buffer.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer if it is allowed to copy from an object to another and it is allowed to copy an object into a buffer and back, how does copying an object into a buffer and then the buffer into a different instance differ from copying the original object directly into the second instance? I never thought it could have been a problem.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Many aspects of C and C++ would be over-specified, needlessly impairing optimizations, if behavioral guarantees were always transitive, but severely under-specified if they were only transitive when explicitly described as such.  Much of what made C useful in the days of simple compilers was that its behavioral guarantees were generally transitive, which meant compilers didn't have to support complex actions directly but could instead let programmers synthesize them out of simple parts.  Making actions only behave transitively when explicitly described as such...

Comment: ...would gut the language, but unfortunately the authors of the C and C++ Standards seem to have adopted that approach rather than saying that actions will *generally* behave transitively, but recognizing exceptions to that principle.

Comment: @supercat maybe I'm too paranoid

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Such paranoia is justified given that some compiler writers either believe that their customers would rather use the under-specified language defined by the Standard than the language the Standard was written to describe, or else don't care that their customers would rather use the latter, but the need for such paranoia is unfortunate in any case.