# Copy trivially copyable types using temporary storage areas: is it allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

This question is a follow up of [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512451/about-aligned-storage-and-trivially-copyable-destructible-types#comment95860813_54518339) to an answer of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512451/about-aligned-storage-and-trivially-copyable-destructible-types).

---

Consider the following example:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(void*), alignof(void*)> storage, copy;

    int i = 42;
    std::memcpy(&storage, &i, sizeof(int));

    copy = storage;

    int j{};
    std::memcpy(&j, &copy, sizeof(int));

    assert(j == 42);
}
```

This *works* (for some definitions of *works*). However, the standard tells us this:

> For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`, the underlying bytes making up the object can be copied into an array of `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte` .
>   If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value. [ Example:
>
> ```
> #define N sizeof(T)
> char buf[N];
> T obj;                          // obj initialized to its original value
> std::memcpy(buf, &obj, N);      // between these two calls to std​::​memcpy, obj might be modified
> std::memcpy(&obj, buf, N);      // at this point, each subobject of obj of scalar type holds its original value
> ```
>
> — end example ]

And this:

> For any trivially copyable type `T`, if two pointers to `T` point to distinct `T` objects `obj1` and `obj2`, where neither `obj1` nor `obj2` is a base-class subobject, if the underlying bytes making up `obj1` are copied into `obj2`, `obj2` shall subsequently hold the same value as `obj1`. [ Example:
>
> ```
> T* t1p;
> T* t2p;
>     // provided that t2p points to an initialized object ...
> std::memcpy(t1p, t2p, sizeof(T));
>     // at this point, every subobject of trivially copyable type in *t1p contains
>     // the same value as the corresponding subobject in *t2p
> ```
>
> — end example ]

In any case it mentions that copying a trivially copyable type in a buffer and then copy it back in a new instance of the original type is allowed.
In the example above I do something similar, plus I copy also the buffer in a new buffer (this resembles a bit more the real world case).

In the comments linked at the top of the question, the author says that this behavior is *underspecified*. On the other side, I cannot see eg how could I send an `int` over the network and use it on the other end if this isn't allowed (copy an `int` in a buffer, send it over the network, receive it as a buffer and memcpy it in an instance of `int` - more or less what I do in the example, without a network in between).

Is this allowed by some other bullets of the standard I missed or is this really *underspecified*?

Comment: Normal programmers should ignore standardese and do the right thing instead. If the right thing doesn't correspond to what the standard actually says, there's a defect in the standard that should be fixed. It should never stop programmers from doing their work. In your case what you do is obviously the right thing, keep doing it.

Comment: @n.m. yeah, I don't expect to change things because the standard doesn't say so. Btw normal programmers are curious sometimes and that's why I ask on SO. ;-) tbh, if you look at the other question, in the original code I didn't even copy objects through a buffer. Instead I placement new them in a buffer, copy the buffer and reinterpret cast it as if it contains an instanced object, even if it doesn't. Someone called it a _benign UB_ and suggested to keep on anyway because a lot of code out there is based on the same assumption that _it just works_.

Comment: @n.m It's (logically) correct to use `union { float; uint32_t; }`, some people use it, gcc toolchain supports type puning since people do it anyway, and it's considered UB by the standard and there's other compilers that actually might invoke UB in this case, what do we do then? There's ways around this that are correct even by the standard but this is still simplest form of solving this problem and IMO should be preferred one... As for the question, you should encode int yourself, so it's not really that right of a thing to do. Remember, Little Endian and Big Endian matters.

Comment: You could also cycle your value through fwrite/fread or similar and ask the same question. Does the standard actually allow us to do IO? (Not a very interesting question to me; if it doesn't, let relevant people fix it). Your other question is a bit different but ultimately can be traced down to a similarly silly question. Namely, does the standard allow us to use malloc like we always do? It might not but who cares.

Comment: @PurpleIce mentioning the network as an example is misleading probably, I'm sorry. I'm not sending data over the network in the real use case, so endianness isn't a problem. The code in the initial example is close to the real use case, everything happens at runtime in the same machine.

Comment: Then it's completely valid use case. Though myself I just resort to exact same bitshifting functions that I wrote to save values in specific endianness without a hassle, since if you save a file on one machine, and move it to another, you will still deal with endianness problems (which is why good file formats specify endianness of values, so everyone uses only specific endianness to load and save, no matter what they are using themselves).

Comment: @PurpleIce it makes sense but this values are not even meant to be saved on file. Just temporarily saved in memory to be reused later by a template function that erase the original type and is able to default construct an instance and memcpy there the original value from the buffer. So, again, don't care about endianness, unless you can prove there exists an architecture that changes suddenly endianness at runtime. :-)

Comment: @PurpleIce no, type punning isn't obviously the right thing to do. Architectures with type-tagged memory simply won't allow you to do this. So the standard is right to classify it as UB. Individual vendors may go ahead and define behaviour of type punning, nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @n.m. do you think is it _safe_ to do also what I was doing originally? That is, instead of a memcpy, perform a placement new in a storage area to copy the original value, then copy the storage and reinterpret cast the copy as if it contains an instance, even though I've never constructed explicitly an instance in the copy. It _works_ to an extent if I set constraints for types (trivially copyable/destructible), but it's UB from the point of view of the standard because literally _the object doesn't exist_.

Comment: You are relying on at least two assumptiins here. 1. If two trivially-copyable objects have the same byte content, no matter how hey got it, they have the same value. If one is valid, then the other is too. 2. An object (trivially copyable?) comes to life as soon as you access memory via an lvalue of the corresponding type. Both assumptions are fairly safe. One is a basis of all binary IO, the other is a basis of using malloc in the traditional way. I don't know if there are any other assumptions.

Comment: @n.m. Indeed no. It's just that in this case the standard says it's UB because you're not explicitly constructing an object when you copy the storage area around. Therefore, to reinterpret cast it is _not allowed_. Not allowed but _it works_ with all major compilers and a lot of code out there probably relies on this anyway, so it won't break any time soon, UB or not.

Comment: @skypjack yes, and that's the reason why `int* x = malloc(sizeof(int)); if(x) *x=42;` is also UB. But absolutely everyone agrees that it's a problem with the standard and this code should be allowed. It's just nobody has came up with a good fix (there are proposals but AFAIK nothing has been accepted yet).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit however, the example in the question isn't explicitly UB. It's unspecified in a sense, but its _correctness_ can be deduced as a consequence of the two bullets, as a combination of them. Otherwise, what would be the _right way_ to do it that is also allowed by the standard? I cannot see it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Granted. I'd be glad if you can give me your opinion on this specific case btw. It seems to me that if it wasn't allowed, a lot of working code out there would be _invalid_.

Comment: @skypjack TBH, it looks fine to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nice to know. The behavior seems correct also to me, even though it derives from a combination of two rules and isn't described explicitly. However it's worth asking sometimes, because SO in an invaluable resource in this case.

Comment: @n.m. has this any chance to match C++20?

Comment: No idea sorry :( We can only hope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It reads fine to me.

You've copied the underlying bytes of `obj1` into `obj2`. Both are trivial and of the same type. The prose you quote permits this explicitly.

The fact that said underlying bytes were temporarily stored in a correctly-sized and correctly-aligned holding area, via an also-explicitly-permitted reinterpretation as `char*`, doesn't seem to change that. They're still "those bytes". There's no rule that says copying must be "direct" in order to satisfy features like this.

Indeed, this is not only a completely common pattern when dealing with network transfer (conventional use of course doesn't make it right on its own), but also a historically normal thing to do that the standard would be *mad* not to account for (which gives me all the assurance I need that it is indeed intended).

I can see how there may be doubt, given that the rule is first given for copying those bytes back into the original object, then given again for copying those bytes into a new object. But I can't detect any logical difference between the two circumstances, and therefore find the first quoted wording to be largely redundant. It's possible the author just wanted to be crystal clear that this safety applies identically in both cases.

Comment: _There's no rule that says copying must be "direct" in order to satisfy features like this_. Good point.

Comment: This rule is simply transitive by definition: if you have 3 objects: obj1, obj2 and obj3, than copying obj1 -> obj2 leaves obj2 exactly the same as obj1. This means that when you define operation that copies obj2 -> obj3, it means that, due to result of first operation, you can change obj2 to obj1 and there will be no difference: obj2 -> obj3 == obj1 -> obj3.

Answer (score 4):

To me, this is one of the most ambiguous issues in C++. Honestly speaking, I never got confused by anything in C++ as much as type punning. There's always a corner case that seems to be not covered (or underspecified, like you put it).

However, conversion from integers [to raw memory (`char*`) is supposed to be allowed for serialization/examination of underlying object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

**What's the solution?**

**Unit tests**. That's my solution to the problem. You do what complies most with the standard, and you write basic unit tests that test your particular assumption. Then, whenever you compile a new version or move to a new compiler, you run the unit tests and verify that the compiler does what you expect it to do.